# Is there any in-canon indication that Rock Lee might be able to use Sage Jutsu?

Tags: naruto, rock-lee

We know Rock Lee has no real talent for *Ninjutsu* or *Genjutsu*, despite heavy training. He also  seems to have no *Kekkei Genkai* (Bloodline Limit trait), which further separated him from talented ninja, and prevented him from gaining incredible powers in those regards. To my knowledge though, those skills were never a requirement for channeling Nature Energy to perform Sage arts; all one had to do was "sit still" and then balance the Nature energy.

Lee has also shown an ability for precise Chakra control by opening the 8 Gates, and he became adept at this by age 13. Opening the Gates take a certain skill in Chakra control, and in most cases requires a pretty fair amount of Chakra itself. Physically speaking, Lee has shown no issues in storing and using Chakra, as it is necessary even for *Taijutsu*. Especially if he saw the "sitting still" as "training", he'd likely dedicate himself to it.

So it *is* possible then, that he could gather and control the Nature energy, just like Chakra, and use that to enhance his ALREADY master-level fighting abilities. Is there any in-manga evidence indicating that Lee, or other ninja like him with limited skills in Ninjutsu or Genjutsu, could *not* do this?